# how to hide an if statment? or whatever technique can be done?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an external javascript file, and it has multiple if statements, the problem is,
one of the if statements is still being called even if the form is hidden.
my application goes like this, 
- when a user is logged-in, hide this particular input form
- if not logged-in, show the input form

so that's the problem, the if statement for that input form using javascript, is still being called even if the input form is hidden, so what should I do to solve this?

here is the if statement for the input form

```
     if(cvusername == "" || cvusername.length < 5 || cvusername.length > 30){
    alert("-username is required\n-should not be less than 5 characters\n and not greater than 30 characters");
    return false;
 }
```

Comment: Do you mean the `<form>` element is not generated (no markup in the page) or only hidden (markup present in the page but hidden to the user)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that your input form's id is input_form, do this:

```
if(document.getElementById("input_form").style.display !== "none"
    && (
        cvusername == ""  
        || cvusername.length < 5
        || cvusername.length > 30) 
    ){
    alert("-username is required\n-should not be less than 5 characters\n and not greater than 30 characters");
    return false;
 }
```

Comment: am not using css to hide the said input form, am using php like e.g  <?php if(!$_SESSION['blah']): ?> <div class="row"><input blah blah /><?php endif; ?>

Answer (score 0):

Either remove that script from your pages or set cvusername to any string between 5 and 30 characters, in every page.

```
cvusername = "loggedin";
```